# Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS When Trying To Access Pointer

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am getting this error and I don't have any idea how to solve it.

[image]

I searched through stack about somewhat similar problem as mine. They say it's memory management problem. When I check debug window(beside the log window, sorry I don't know what it's called), I noticed that the value pointed by the pointers are all NULL. How can I retain them?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Is dominantColor ok?

Answer (score 0):

pass float value in colorWithRed:

```
 UIColor *bgcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(float) green:(float) blue:(float) alpha:(float)];
```

pass float value in palce of passing pointer type .

hope it helps you .

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I am already passing a float value there, *red is value pointed by the pointer "red", which is a float value. If I am passing a pointer type, then it should be just "red", and there would definitely be a compile time error.